# need to download Stormpath Java SDK .jars to my application using Maven from github

Tags: maven, github, stormpath

I need to know how to download Stormpath Java SDK .jars and add them to my java web application using Maven from GitHub. I am using Netbeans IDE.

I am using http://docs.stormpath.com/java/quickstart/ instructions and https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/

I am not sure of how to Add the Stormpath SDK into my project in netbeans.

Please give me step by step instruction

Comment: Please specify the issues you encountered while setting it up, so that the question would be more specific.

Comment: This is the github link https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java from where i need to download jars. How can i do that and then i need to add to the local maven repositoty?

Comment: where is the jar file

Comment: Github lets me download a zip file. I need to know how to add it to local maven repo

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by the question - this is documented in the servlet quickstart.  Just add this to your maven pom.xml file in the `<dependencies>` section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.stormpath.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>stormpath-servlet-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${stormpath.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Where `${stormpath.version}` is whatever version you want.  At the time of this writing, that is `1.0.RC9`.

After doing that and running `mvn clean install`, the SDK and its necessary dependencies will automatically be downloaded to your local `~/.m2/repository` cache.

If this isn't enough information, there are tutorials for [using Netbeans with Maven](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html) to help understand how the two work together.